# What is meant by "a length typical of the large-scale vorticity distribution"?

Tags: definition, intuition, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics, research

Apologies if this isn't the right place for this question. I guess it's somewhat research-related, but it seemed too basic to ask on mathoverflow.

I'm working through a [paper](http://www-vortex.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~dgd/papers/d88c.pdf) (pdf) involving a technique to redistribute points along a contour. The details aren't really important, I don't think. All I'm trying to understand is what is meant by:

> L is a length typical of the large-scale vorticity distribution
>
> [Bottom of third page of the pdf, right after the centred equations]

Can someone explain what this means?